# How to show error state for wrong password on Firebase Simple Login email password

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, firebase

I'm using Firebase's [Simple Login](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-email-password.html) as an admin login for a blog format site. The correct email and pw combo gives write access to the db on Firebase. Following the documentation I have created separate chunks.

The auth var:

```
var chatRef = new Firebase('https://fiery-fire-291.firebaseio.com/');

var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(chatRef, function(error, user) {
    if (error) {
        // an error occurred while attempting login
        console.log(error);
    } else if (user) {
        // user authenticated with Firebase
        console.log('User ID: ' + user.id + ', Provider: ' + user.provider);
    } else {
    // user is logged out
    }
});
```

The auth login, which I've wrapped in a login controller:

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.login = function() {
        auth.login('password', {
            email: $scope.loginEmail,
            password: $scope.loginPassword, 
            debug: true 
        });
    };
});
```

Which gets the data from the login form:

```
<div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
    <form ng-submit="login()">
        <fieldset ng-class="">
            <input type="email" ng-model="loginEmail">
            <input type="password" ng-model="loginPassword">
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" href="#">Login</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

What would be the correct/best way of setting the ng-class to error for the login form to show the user when their Firebase login has errored?

I feel like I shouldn't set the CSS in Angular (which I could easily do in the error callback). I've tried setting a global var in the callbacks which would be picked up by

```
ng-class="{error: !userAuthenticated}"
```

but apart from not working, I feel this is also wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method here is to write the error to `$scope` within the callback. You'll need to alert Angular to [start a compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler) by calling $apply or $timeout:

```
var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(chatRef, function(error, user) {
    $timeout(function() {
       if (error) {
           $scope.error = error;
       } else if (user) {
           $scope.error = null;
       } else {
          $scope.error = 'user is logged out';
       }
    });
});
```

Display it in your page:

```
<p class="error" ng-show="error">{{error}}</p>
```

You can save yourself a good deal of effort by utilizing the in-place tools for Angular + Firebase development: [Angular+Firebase Quick Start](https://www.firebase.com/quickstart/angularjs.html), [angularFire library](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire), [angularfire-seed](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed)

The angularFire-seed contains a complete, functional login example, including error handling, which you can reference as well.

Comment: Cool, that makes sense, thanks. That seed app is the most useful, combined with the Angularfire api docs.
I see they use this [simpleLoginTools.js module](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/7328023) for showing/hiding bits when logged in, which I would never have found otherwise.

Comment: Also the directive example on the compiler doc was useful.

Answer (score 1):

I am not all that familiar with Angular at all but having looked at the Firebase documentation I believe the callback is *exactly* were you are meant to do this, it's what it's there for. From the docs:

```
auth.createUser(email, password, function(error, user) {
  if (!error) {
    console.log('User Id: ' + user.id + ', Email: ' + user.email);
  }
});
```

If you want to keep out the CSS itself from the controllers then I advise having a look at [this snippet on Coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/r3_geg) that goes into how the ng-class can be set not just via a classname but by an *object + expression*. You could then set the given boolean controlling the ng-class as required in the error callback and your angular template will update accordingly yet you've not "mixed in" the class setting to your controller code.

Comment: This could also work, I guess the thing to take away is in this case the auth js has to be in the login controller for either way you do it.
Also don't be scared to manipulate the DOM through a directive. I misremembered part of http://toddmotto.com/ultimate-guide-to-learning-angular-js-in-one-day/ - 
_"It's important to remember that Controllers are for data only, and creating functions (event functions too!) that talk to the server and push/pull JSON data. No DOM manipulation should be done here, so put your jQuery toolkit away. Directives are for DOM manipulation"_